# Getting an EditText data from a ListView Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am actually new to Android Programming and I am developing an application in which I have a listView,which only comprises of EditTexts (i.e.TextInputEditText).
I have added hints to the EditTexts, but I want to get values from the EditText that the users enter.

Here is my code:

MyItems.java

```
public class MyItem {
public String TextTitle;
EditText Message;
public MyItem(String title)
{
    this.TextTitle = title;
}
public EditText getEditText() {
    return Message;
}`enter code here`
public void setEditText(EditText msg) {
    this.Message = msg;
}
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<MyItem> listItems;
private Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyItem> listItems)
{
   this.context=context;
   this.listItems=listItems;
}
@Override
public int getCount()
{
   return listItems.size();
}
@Override
public MyItem getItem(int position)
{
    return listItems.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row;
    ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(view == null) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, parent, false);
    listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
    listViewHolder.tvname = row.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
    row.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        row = view;
        listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    try {
        MyItem myItem = getItem(position);
        String text = myItem.TextTitle;
        listViewHolder.tvname.setHint(text);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException exec)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Execption ");
    }
    EditText etText = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.etText);
    listItems.get(position).setEditText(etText);
    return row;
}
}
```

MainFragment

```
public class ExistingStudentFragment extends Fragment {
Button btnExisting, btnNew;
Button btnShow, btnSubmit;
ArrayList<MyItem> myitems=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<MyItem> myitems2=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<MyItem> myitems3=new ArrayList<>();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.existing_student_fragment, 
container, false);
    getTextView();
    getTextView2();
    getTextView3();
    ListView listView, listView2, listView3;
    final MyAdapter myAdapter, myAdapter2, myAdapter3;
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_items);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), myitems);
    listView2 = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_items2);
    myAdapter2 = new MyAdapter(getContext(), myitems2);
    listView3 = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_items3);
    myAdapter3 = new MyAdapter(getContext(), myitems3);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    listView2.setAdapter(myAdapter2);
    listView3.setAdapter(myAdapter3);
    Spinner spinner_pass = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spin_passtype);
    List<String> passtype = new ArrayList<String>();
    passtype.add("Ist Class");
    passtype.add("IInd Class");
    ArrayAdapter<String> SpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
       (this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, passtype);
SpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdownitem);
    spinner_pass.setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter);

    btnExisting = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnExisting);
    btnNew = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
    btnShow = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnshow);
    btnSubmit = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);

    btnExisting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((UserConcessionActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(0);
        }
    });
    btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((UserConcessionActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(1);
        }
    });

    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msg = myAdapter.getItem(0).getEditText().toString();
        }
    });
        return view;
}

private void getTextView()
{

    myitems.add(new MyItem("Admission Number:"));
    myitems.add(new MyItem("Roll Number:"));
    myitems.add(new MyItem("Name Of Student:"));
    myitems.add(new MyItem("Stream:"));
}

private void getTextView2()
{
    myitems2.add(new MyItem("Last Certificate Number(VCH No):"));
    myitems2.add(new MyItem("Last Ticket from(Station):"));
    myitems2.add(new MyItem("Last Ticket Number(Last 4 digits):"));
    myitems2.add(new MyItem("Last Ticket Period(Monthly/Quaterly):"));
    myitems2.add(new MyItem("Last Issued Date:"));
}

private void getTextView3()
{
    myitems3.add(new MyItem("From Station:"));
    myitems3.add(new MyItem("Pass Type(I or II):"));
    myitems3.add(new MyItem("Ticket Period:"));
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you please tell us which `EditText` did you mean to get the text? Haven't you tried `getText.toString()`?

Comment: TextInputEditText its a newer version of EditText.
No, unable to getText using that code

Answer (score 0):

> [**TextInputEditText**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText) extends from `AppCompatEditText` and,
>
> **From the documentation:**
>
> **A special sub-class of `EditText`** designed for use as a child of
>   TextInputLayout.
>
> Using this class allows us to display a hint in the IME when in
>   'extract' mode.

So you should be able to get text like following codes from `TextInputEditText`:

```
String retrievedText = textInputName.getText().toString();
```

Don't forget to define in java-kotlin side with a prefix of your `Fragment` view (`view` in your case):

```
TextInputEditText textInputName = view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_edit_word_1);
```

And also in Xml layout.

There is also a good sample [**in here**](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText) which you can use.

Comment: But its all defined in listView so how will i retrieve it from the list?

Comment: `but I want to get values from the EditText that the users enter.` If this is exactly what you're asking then, my answer will help.

Comment: yes but I have added the edittext in a listView so how should I retrieve

Comment: Sorry. I think you misunderstand the use of `ListView` and `EditText`. Don't get how you added the `EditText` in a `ListView`. Those are different widgets with different usages...